# How do I get the IP address of the desktop from windows mobile when cradled using .NET CF?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

I am developing a windows mobile 6 application using .NET CF 3.5.  I need to get the IP address of my desktop computer when the device is cradled in order to initiate a synchronization process from the mobile device.

I have tried Dns.GetHostEntry, but this seems to return the IP address of my Pocket PC emulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be working now.  I think I had another synchronization problem that was being returned as a connection issue.

Here is my code in case anyone else is trying to do this:

            var hostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("PPP_Peer");

            var ipAddress = hostEntry.AddressList[0].ToString();

Comment: If this has solved your problem, you should post it as the answer to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Yes, please post as an answer, not only is it alright, it is [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). And then you can get more reputation when someone up-votes it because it has helped them ;)